# How does one create a slide-in DIV at the edge of the window?

Tags: jquery, css

This is a rather cool effect... I looked up something on this page and noticed the slide-in window that loads in like a minute or so after you arrive on the page. It slides in from the right, stays there at 250x180 for about ten seconds, then shrinks to a 250 x 50 and stays visible for a while.

I would love to re-create this window and use it as a live-chat link on our page.

I would love to know if there is a way to do this with jQuery/CSS.

Can you guys check out the window (It's a "Recommended for You" slide-in) on this page: [Page with slide-in window](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2010/01/css-transitions-101/) and give me some guidance on how to recreate it using jQuery?

It takes a minute to load in (FYI)... Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's just a Wordpress plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simplereach-slide/

Comment: I just want to recreate the effect, not the functionality. The slide I saw was definately the SimpleReach plugin though lol

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myTimeout = window.setTimeout(function() {
    $(myDiv).animate({
        left: '-=100%'
    });
}, 60000);
```

Providing that your div is off of the right side of the screen.